How to Inject runtime parameters when resolving a service in .NET Dependency Injection?
I have a repository class which has an implementation that uses the File System.
Repository Abstraction
    public interface IPersonRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Person> GetAll();

        Person Get(Guid id);

        void Add(Person person);
    }

Repository Implmentation
    public class JsonPersonRepository : IPersonRepository
    {
        private readonly string _josnContainerFolder;
        private readonly ICollection<Person> _people;
        private readonly IFileSystemProvider _fileSystemProvider;
        private readonly IJsonSerializerWrapper _jsonSerializer;

        public JsonTestPlanRepository(string josnContainerFolder, IFileSystemProvider fileSystemProvider, IJsonSerializerWrapper jsonSerializer)
        {
            _josnContainerFolder= testPlansFolderPath;
            _fileSystemProvider = fileSystemProvider;
            _jsonSerializer = jsonSerializer;

            _people = GetPeopleFromFilesOfDirectories();
        }

        // Rest of Implementation
}

How can I inject these parameters while I resolve it with .NET DI, something like this?
services.AddScoped<Func<string, PersonRepository>>(sp => (folder) => sp.GetRequiredService<PersonRepository>(folder));

I've attempted to provide jsonContainerFolder as startup data using Configuration. However, due to the application's dynamic folder change requirement at runtime, this approach is not feasible.


Factory Method with Func<>: You’re on the right track with the Func<string, PersonRepository> approach. However, there’s a small correction needed. Instead of resolving ConditionView, you should resolve your JsonPersonRepository directly. Here’s how you can do it:
services.AddScoped<Func<string, JsonPersonRepository>>(sp => folder =>
{
var fileSystemProvider = sp.GetRequiredService();
var jsonSerializer = sp.GetRequiredService();
return new JsonPersonRepository(folder, fileSystemProvider, jsonSerializer);
});

Now, whenever you need an instance of JsonPersonRepository, you can
inject the Func<string, JsonPersonRepository> and call it with the
desired folder path.
ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<>: Another approach is to use
ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider, Object[]).
This allows you to create an instance of your repository class with
constructor parameters. Here’s how you can use it:
services.AddSingleton(sp =>
{
var folder = "your_dynamic_folder_path"; // Set this dynamically based on your application's requirements
return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(sp, folder, sp.GetRequiredService(), sp.GetRequiredService());
});

Custom Factory: If you have more complex logic for creating instances, consider creating a custom factory class that encapsulates the creation process. For example:


public class PersonRepositoryFactory
{
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
public PersonRepositoryFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}

public JsonPersonRepository Create(string folder)
{
    var fileSystemProvider = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IFileSystemProvider>();
    var jsonSerializer = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IJsonSerializerWrapper>();
    return new JsonPersonRepository(folder, fileSystemProvider, jsonSerializer);
}

}
// Register the factory
services.AddSingleton();
